# Insert file content in `varbinary` column

Tags: sql-server

I need to write a simple SQL script to insert a new line to a table with a `varbinary` column that is supposed to hold the content of files. I have tried :

```
DECLARE @FileContent varbinary(max)
SET @FileContent = SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'pathToFile', SINGLE_BLOB);

INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([Name], [Content])
VALUES ('Dummy', @FileContent)
```

But it does not compile...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose in round brackets SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET

```
DECLARE @FileContent varbinary(max)
SET @FileContent = (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'pathToFile', SINGLE_BLOB) tmp);

INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([Name], [Content])
VALUES ('Dummy', @FileContent)
```

Comment: how, ok, just brackets... Thanks !

Comment: SET @FileContent = (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'pathToFile', SINGLE_BLOB) x);